# How to set a flash drive on readonly?

Tags: c++, c, winapi

I'd like to set a USB flash drive on readonly in C++ .

I found a solution using diskpart with a text file as parameter, but doing so in command prompt does not work (whereas using diskpart without the text file works). Plus, if possible, I'd like to avoid having to use a third text file.

I took a look at libusb, but found nothing in it to link a device with its drive letter (which I need at least for the UI).

I've tried SetFileAttributes, but it ends with the "Invalid parameter" error.

How could I do this ?

Thank you.

[Edit] : I'm working with Win32.

Comment: There is an ioctl to call under Linux for block devices to set them read-only.

Comment: If the filesystem on your USB flash drive is NTFS, then you could use the Windows security API to disallow write access to "everybody". But this API is rather difficult to use. If the filsystem is FAT32 or EFS I don't think this is possible.

Answer (score 4):

you need use [`IOCTL_DISK_SET_DISK_ATTRIBUTES`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh706682(v=vs.85).aspx) for this and also [`IOCTL_DISK_GET_DISK_ATTRIBUTES`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh706681(v=vs.85).aspx) for query.

1. so we need open `"\\\\?\\PhysicalDrive<X>"` with
   `FILE_READ_DATA|FILE_WRITE_DATA` for set. for query access can be
   any
2. init [`SET_DISK_ATTRIBUTES`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh706683(v=vs.85).aspx)

   ```
   SET_DISK_ATTRIBUTES sda = { sizeof(sda), TRUE };// not sizeof(GET_DISK_ATTRIBUTES).as in documentation, this mistake 
   sda.AttributesMask = DISK_ATTRIBUTE_READ_ONLY;
   sda.Attributes = DISK_ATTRIBUTE_READ_ONLY;
   ```
3. and `DeviceIoControl( hDevice, IOCTL_DISK_SET_DISK_ATTRIBUTES, &sda,
   sizeof(sda), 0, 0, 0);`

however this will be work begin form windows 7 only