# Setting USB keys in read-only mode from registry

Tags: c#, windows

Can you remount a drive in read-only mode in C#? I see that with `diskpart` you can set a disk to read-only, but that will actually change the disk. Is there something similar to Linux, where you can mount a disk in read-only mode?

If not, what's the best alternative?

What I'm trying to achieve is to make read-only some USB drives as soon as they are plugged in. I'm listening to this event

```
WqlEventQuery eventQuery = new WqlEventQuery();
eventQuery.EventClassName = "__InstanceCreationEvent";
eventQuery.WithinInterval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 3);
eventQuery.Condition = @"TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_USBHub'";
```

But it doesn't contain the volume where the disk is mounted, so I don't know how to identify that with `diskpart`.

What do you suggest?

More details: I'm writing a program that detects when a USB storage device is attached and if matches some conditions the device is set in read-only mode.

Comment: I don't even know how to begin with questions.. there is so much unclear about this question.. From what part of the OS do you want tot start - is this program on the USB or always running - what have you tried, what even is a WqlEvent - more details are needed

Comment: Added more details, please let me know if that's still unclear

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40676088/how-to-set-a-flash-drive-on-readonly, should be fairly simple to convert to C#

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40676088/how-to-set-a-flash-drive-on-readonly

Comment: In addition to Charlieface comments: [IVdsVolume::SetFlags method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/vds/nf-vds-ivdsvolume-setflags)